# Yii- How can I make the second dropdownlist values displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I'm new to Yii framework and Javascript. Now, I'm using two dropdownlists for min_cost and max_cost. I'm using the below code to list the values in the dropdownlist.

```
<?php 
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'min_cost',
    'data' => Yii::app()->params['cost_min_resales'],
    'options' => array(
        'onSelect' => 'cost_change(item.value);',
        'allowText' => false,
    ),     
    'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min Cost', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
));
?>

</br>

<?php 
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'max_cost',
    'data' =>Yii::app()->params['cost_max_resales'],
    'options' => array(                    
        'allowText' => false,
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Max Cost', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
));                       
?>
```

For this I'm using the below script:

```
<script>
    function cost_change(price) {
        var removed;
        console.log("removed", removed);
        select = "#SearchForm_max_cost_select";
        var value = price;
        console.log("value", value);
        jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').prepend(removed);
        var toKeep = jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter(function() {
            return parseInt(this.value) > parseInt(value);
        });

        console.log("to keep",toKeep);
        removed =  jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter(function() {
            return parseInt(this.value) < parseInt(value);
        });           
    }
</script>
```

Now, I want to populate the second dropdownlist with values greater than the value selected in first one. Suppose there are values hardcoded in an array as (1,2,3,4,5) I select 2 from first dropdownlist then all values greater than 2 (i.e 3,4,5) should be listed in second dropdownlist.
The above script works fine. I can see the values of second dropdownlist printed in the logs . But, I'm not able to pass this values to second dropdownlist. How can I do this.

Edit : 
Below is the image of the object I'm getting when I select value .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this will work, actually i was also facing the same problem but somehow figured it out.

In your controller just check for this condition..

```
 if ($model->"yourdbid" == null) {
  $model->"yourdbid" = $_POST['yourdbid'];
```

}